# Merge flat files

Tags: mainframe, utilities, jcl

I am trying to create a JCL for merging flat files using IEBGENER. The number of input files is not constant. Can we do it using IEBGENER?

Comment: How do you specify the input files? Directly in the JCL or from some other source?

Comment: We have one job which is calling proc. Proc has IEBGENR step. The file numbers is not fixed.I was thinking of using symbolic parameters inside proc and passing these values from job.Is there any other way to do that? We cant have gdgs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you override `IEBGENER SYSUT1 DD` when invoking the `PROC`? Something like:

```
//EXEC procedure
//procstep.SYSUT1 DD DSN=first.copy.file,DISP=SHR,
//          DSN=second.copy.file,DISP=SHR,
//          DSN=thrid.copy.file,DISP=SHR
etcetera...
```

Where `procedure` is the catalogued procedure and `procstep` is the IEBGENER step.

When multiple datasets are
given for a single DD statement they are concatenated together. As far
as `IEBGENER` is concerned they should look like a single input dataset.

Comment: I can give an override from job.In this case do we need to give SYSUT1 as DUMMY in PROC? and then override dataset names from JOB.am i correct??

Comment: Doesn't matter what SYSUT1 points to in the PROC, when you override it from your job it is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple to do when we have input file count is not certain by the time job runs. Get the files from source created as generations of a `GDG base` and specify the base as input, which takes all the generations created so far... but every time the generations created so far will be considered; to avoid it; create a temp file with data from all generations and delete all of them, so that next time you'll have fresh set of generations to be considered. Am i clear? lemme know if not!

Answer (score 0):

A. If you cannot have GDG's then empty files for the missing ones, in particular you then need to have a limit (10, 20 ?).

B. if you are using Control-M or similar , you can pre-process in the DD statement with an INCLUDE. The job cannot be submitted until the include material is ready, and it must be a separate job. That is to say, dynamically build your JCL from alternative decks based on the number of files.

C. You may have to write a program or CLIST to test for existence and concatenate the files.

Anybody that is using GDG's and reading them all at once should always remember the lastest generations are read first.